# Apache Domain not pointing to DocumentRoot (DigitialOcean Moodle)

Tags: apache, ssl, moodle, digital-ocean

I am running ubuntu 18.4, having the digitalocean lamp installtion including the quickstart ssl. I successfully installed the moodle application in on the server in subdirectory `/var/www/html/moodle`.

My question is as follows:
how do I point my subfolder to the main domain, e.g. https://example.org/moodle to https://example.org

My suggestion would be simple change the apache site-enabled/moodle.conf DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/moodle`.

This had no effect. Visiting the  https://example.org just displays the `/var/www/html/index.html` file from digitalocean.

Strangely even if I pointed the documentroot to a non existing one, like `/var/www/html/moodle_2` it also had no effect.

My guess was that the moodle.conf is not being used. 
(-> Why?? How to activate it? running `sudo a2ensite moodle.conf` resulted in `Site moodle already enabled`)

Now, I moved and started to change the settings in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`. This had a direct effect.

if I set there the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/moodle`my server was not displaying anything. Meaning, beforehand he was displaying the default digitalocean site when you go to the domain. and was displaing the moodle app when you navigated to example.org/moodle . Now I just receive the message. /moodle not found.

I just want to use moodle as default site when going to example.org.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

I followed this tutorial to install moodle: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-moodle-on-ubuntu-16-04

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `.htaccess` file with the following content solves this problem perfectly, since it is in a subfolder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moodle/

# Rewrites all URLS [Replace "example" with the actual domain, without the TLD (.com, .net, .biz, etc)]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /moodle/$1 [L]
```